# Read Downloaded Text File - Android

Tags: android, file, text, inputstream

So my program works like this:
It downloads a .txt file from the dropbox and saves it to downloads directory.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(file);
DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

// This put the download in the same Download dir the browser uses
r.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "upload");

r.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

// Start download
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
dm.enqueue(r);
```

And the code is working fine, it downloads the file called upload.txt.
So now i want to read from it. I have been looking for some codes and nothing seems to be working...
Here is my current code, it throws a FileNotFoundException but file is located there.
Any tips?

```
String text="";
    FileInputStream Fin=new FileInputStream(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"upload");
    byte[] b=new byte[100];
    Fin.read(b);
    text=new String(b);
    Fin.close();
```

Ofc i have tried putting "upload.txt", and even "/upload" and "/upload.txt" but still nothing.
If anyone can give me code that reads a text file, it would be awesome, or if someone could give me a code that can get the source code form a html site ( without JSOUP and other parsers, i have tried that, i want to implement my own parser ).
Thanks!!

Comment: do you have the correct permissions? You need permission to read files from the SD card for this to work!

Comment: Yes, i have read and write external storage permissions... I think i don't require any more, do i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
FileInputStream Fin=new FileInputStream(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"upload");
```

to

```
FileInputStream Fin=new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "upload"));
```

You should use [`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) to get the path.

---

Or if you like more,

```
FileInputStream Fin=new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/upload");
```

---

Change

```
r.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "upload");
```

too with

```
r.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "upload");
```

Comment: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` has been deprecated, do you have a new solution?

Answer (score 0):

Took me ages, but finally:
You should add to the manifest the various permissions (android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE...)

But this is not enough!
you should explicitly ask for these permissions in the onCreate():

requestPermissions({android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,...}, 200);

Only afterwards you can access these directories.